# Nginx + HapiJS CORS request (not GET)

Tags: nginx, cors, hapi.js

I have a node server with a hapiJS API, and am attempting to send it requests from a separate Node server.

Everything works fine in development, but not on the servers, and the issue is basic auth is enabled on the servers.

Specifically, the requests work fine if they are GET requests, but all other requests fail. I *suspect* this is due to the OPTIONS pre-request flight check failing, which isn't sent on GET requests from my limited understanding.

The exact error message I get is:

**No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://site.example.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.**

My nginx config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name https://api.example.com;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri; ## Permanently redirect all http traffic to https
}
server {

  #SSL INIT
  listen  443;
  ssl    on;
  ssl_certificate    /var/vcap/jobs/nginx/config/site.bundle.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key    /var/vcap/jobs/nginx/config/site.key;

  server_name https://api.example.com;

  location / {
    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_pass https://api.example.com;
  }

}
```

And my CORS settings for HapiJS (I excluded the irrelevant stuff).

```
connections:
  routes:
    cors:
      origin: ["https://api.example.com"]
      credentials: true
```

I have tried the https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-cors-headers hapi-cors-headers plugin, to no avail (instead of the above settings.) I tried enabling every single CORS thing on nginx I could think of (most of them gotten from http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html)

One of two things happens, no matter how I've adjusted the configuration - and I've tried a LOT of things:
1) It continues to give the above message no matter what
2) It complains about the heading being there TWICE (if I put it in both nginx and hapijs at the same time).

In no situation does it work (except GET requests).

An example of a POST ajax call to the API that I'm using (used with Kendo):

```
$.ajax({
    url: api_address + '/vendors',
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    processData: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(this.vendor),
    xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
    }
    success: function(data) {

        vm.set('vendor', data);
        notification.show('Vendor created successfully', 'success');
        vm.set('has_changes', false);
    },
    error: function() {
        notification.show('Error creating vendor', 'error');
    }
});
```

the api_address mentioned above is:

```
https://username:password@api.example.com
```

Why is this working for GET requests but not POST/PUT/etc?

Answer (score 0):

Change your nginx to handle the CORS and don't have hapi worry about it. Taken and modified from http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html

```
location / {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';

    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        #
        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
    }
    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_pass https://api.example.com;
}
```

Of course you would need more work if you are supporting PUT or DELETE.